# Copy text from both sides of colon

Tags: regex, parsing, notepad++

Currently I have 75k lines of text but im trying to figure out how to only copy the text from the colons. The text file looks like this. Id only like to get the QQQQ:EEEE and UUUU:IIII

```
QQQQ:EEEE
-------------------------------------------
Apples
Organges
Banana
Grapes
--------------------------------------------


UUUU:IIII
---------------------------------------------
Carrots
Beets
Watermelon
Melon
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `\w+:\w+` should work in Notepad++

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/L263k5/1)